# Is it safe to call system(3) from multi-threaded process?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, fork

`system()` function is implemented by using `fork()`, `execve()` and `wait()` functions.
I have heard that `fork()` function is dangerous in multi-threaded programs.
So, is the `system()` function also dangerous in multi-threaded programs?

What problems it may cause?

Comment: Check this out, this may help http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/threads-and-fork-think-twice-before-using-them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fork` is dangerous in threaded programs **unless** followed by `execve`. Since only the current thread is forked there's very little you can do in a forked multi-threaded program other than `execve`. You should probably make sure you're not taking any locks after the `fork`.

Since `system()` does `fork` + `exec`, it should be safe.

Comment: It is not safe. File descriptors may leak

Answer (score 8):

The `system()` function isn't necessarily thread-safe.

[POSIX.1-2008 specifies](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html#tag_16_597_03) (as well as POSIX.1-2001):

> The system() function need not be thread-safe.

For example, [Solaris 10 documents `system()` as thread-unsafe](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=system&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=SunOS+5.10&arch=default&format=html#end):

> The system() function manipulates the  signal  handlers  for
>   SIGINT,  SIGQUIT,  and  SIGCHLD. It is therefore not safe to
>   call system() in a multithreaded process, since  some  other
>   thread  that  manipulates these signal handlers and a thread
>   that concurrently calls system()  can  interfere  with  each
>   other  in  a destructive manner.

This man page also suggests `popen()` as thread-safe work-around. Note that `popen()` doesn't change any signal handlers.

On Linux, [`system()` is thread-safe](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html).

Note that `system()` doesn't necessarily calls `fork()`. A implementation could use `vfork()`, instead. Or, on Linux, it could directly call `clone()`. It could even use `posix_spawn()`.

Although [forking in a multi-threaded program can be challenging](http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/threads-and-fork-think-twice-before-using-them),  a fork directly followed by an exec is safe, in general (modulo open file descriptors).

Answer (score 2):

Fork is dangerous in multithreaded programs because it does not copy all running threads. It should be ok with system, but if you have signal handlers and multiple threads wait()ing you could again have a mess.